# Determine whether or not it can be guaranteed that a local optimal solution will be a global optimal solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

$$
 \max  (a  x_1^{1/2} -bx_2e^{x_2}+cx_3)
$$
subject to
\begin{align}
x_1+3x_2+2x_3&\leq10\\
x_1^3+x_2^2&\leq20\\
x_1,x_2,x_3&\geq0\\
\end{align}
(Assignment problem)
My approach: The answer depends on sign of $b$ nothing is mentioned in question so I am assuming $a$, $b$ and $c$ to be positive. So to maximize the given expression $x_2$ must be 0. The answer again depends on the value of $a$ and $c$. How do I find local optimal solution here.

Comment: Observe, that the region is compact and the function is continuous. Hence there exists a global maximum. (And it is a local one as well.)

Comment: @Jochen Can you elaborate

Comment: Of course, from equations (1) and (3) follows $0\leq x_1, x_2, x_3\leq 10$. Hence our region is bounded. It's closed as the preimage of a continuous function on a closed set ($(-\infty,10]\times(-\infty,20]\times[0,\infty)^3$). There is a theorem, that the supremum of a continuous function on a compact region will be attained.